# Is there an alternative to getUserMedia for Phonegap Android(local)?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, getusermedia

I found a few questions on Stackoverflow like this but no answer yet. I'm trying to stream camera input from an Android device to a HTML5 video tag for some real-time image processing. The Camera plugin for Phonegap does not support this so I tried using getUserMedia. This almost worked except that Chrome does not support the file:// protocol for getUserMedia, where the video stream is stored(I believe). It works when I run it from a server but I want to be able to use this app locally, without an Internet connection. Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In case anybody runs into this issue, I solved it by using Crosswalk which builds the apk with it's own webkit that provides getUserMedia.